# frame.setResizable(false) does not work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

How do I disable the feature of resizing my `JFrame`?

My Code is as follows the `frame.setResizable(false)` does not work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SearchIncome frame = new SearchIncome();
                frame.setResizable(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public SearchIncome()
{     
    setTitle("DPSS: Search Income");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 790, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images\\icon.jpg"));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your frame shouldn't be displayed too. Because, I don't see you called setVisible for JFrame.

Comment: But where do you call setVisible for JFrame then?

Comment: in a previous page and class -SearchIncome page = new SearchIncome();
    page.setVisible(true);

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: it is ok i have it working now it is SearchIncome page = new SearchIncome();
    page.setVisible(true);
    page.setResizable(false); Thanks!

Comment: Simple solution, bad mistake! You obviously have 2 main methods. You are setting `setResizable(false)` for `frame` instance and not for `page` instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous class where i call the class with the code above i should have entered this:

```
 SearchIncome page = new SearchIncome(); 
 page.setVisible(true); 
 page.setResizable(false)
```

When opening the page! thanks for the help!